# Как получить следующий элемент?

Tags: c#

Я хочу получать следующие число а когда получаю последнее получать первое.
У меня есть код

```
public enum Week
{
    MON,
    TUE,
    WED,
    THU,
    FRI,
    SAT,
    SUN
}
static Week GetNextValue(Week val){
    if(val < Week.SUN)
        return val + 1;
    return Week.MON ;
}
```

Но он работает только с Week а мне нужно что бы он работал со всеми enum.
Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Проблема вашего метода не только в том, что он заточен под один enum, а еще в том, что он делает +1, когда элементы enum могут иметь совершенно разные числовые значения, ведь C# позволяет написать так: `MON = 1, TUE = 22, WED = 333`, что будет, если мы возьмем в таком случае `TUE` (у которого числовое значение 22) и сделаем +1? Правильно, будет 23. А есть ли у нас 23 в указанном enum? Так что, здесь надо идти в сторону получения массива значений, а уж затем их перебирать, оперируя индексами. А "универсальность" - за это отвечает Generic. [Пример решения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/643438).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я пытался вставить этот код для теста но получил ошибку `Assets\Scripts\GameManagerScr.cs(14,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ArgumentException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` И еще я заметил что он просто переводит enum в массив. Но я так и не понял как передать Enum. Единственное что я видел это примеры тип `static Week GetNextValue(Week val)` где GetNextValue принимает только параметры из Week. и как сделать `Week.WED.Next();` я не знаю

Comment: Ошибка говорит вам о том, что не подключили namespace, в котором находится `ArgumentException`. Нажмите на эту строку, там будет лампочка рядом , жмете на нее и должно предложить подключение всего необходимого. `И еще я заметил что он просто переводит enum в массив` - он делает тоже, что и ваш код, только не простым +1, а берет все значения указанного enum, пропускает те, что не подходят под указанное значение, а затем берет следующее. `Но я так и не понял как передать Enum.` - вызов аналогичен вашему коду. `как сделать Week.WED.Next();` - если вам такое нужно, то это уже метод расширения.